# How does express server send data to the React client?

Tags: reactjs, express, server, oauth-2.0, discord

I try to implement web browser that can login to discord by Oauth2 with backend express server.
My server can take request from the client and redirect to the discord api that contains user information.
Now, my server holds the user info and try to send it back to the client.
However, I couldn't find any solution that can send user info into the client.

How can I send user info (maybe json) to the client?
Here is my code.

## NavBar.js in client

```
class NavBar extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar nav-background">
                <ul className="nav-list">
                    <Link className="logo" to="/home">
                        <img src={logo} alt='img'/>
                    </Link>
                    <li><Link to="/bot" className="nav-link">MessageShark Bot</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/join" className="nav-link">Join Our Discord</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/command" className="nav-link">Command</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/help" className="nav-link">Help</Link></li>
                </ul>
                <div className="rightNav">
                    <a className="btn btn-oauth"
                       href='http://localhost:47044/api/discord/login'
                    >Login with Discord</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
export default NavBar;
```

## index.js in server

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const discordRouter = require('./api/discord');
app.use('/api/discord', discordRouter);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    switch (err.message) {
        case 'NoCodeProvided':
            return res.status(400).send({
                status: 'ERROR',
                error: err.message,
            });
        default:
            return res.status(500).send({
                status: 'ERROR',
                error: err.message,
            });
    }
});

app.listen(47044, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on 47044`);
});
```

## discord.js in server

```
const express = require('express');
const { catchAsync } = require('../utils');
const router = express.Router();
const { clientId, clientSecret, port  } = require('../config.json');
const redirect = `http://localhost:${port}/api/discord/callback`;

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&scope=identify&redirect_uri=${redirect}`);
});

router.get('/callback', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: redirect,
        code: req.query.code,
        scope: ['identify', 'email', 'guilds'],
    };
    const response = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new URLSearchParams(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    })
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    const fetchDiscordUserInfo = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${json.access_token}`,
        }
    });
    const user = await fetchDiscordUserInfo.json();
    console.log(user);
    res.json(user)
    //res.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
}));
```

Comment: if it's a link like that the best you can do is set a cookie and redirect. Then on the next page you can do a fetch that sends the cookie and gets the data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out axios! https://axios-http.com/docs/intro

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a way for your frontend to call things in the backend (express server).

If you have all your OAuth stuff in the backend, and you need to call it from a React component, say, a button, then you can write a function that runs axios.get([params]) and maybe location.redirect afterwards (I'm guessing a lot of what you want to do next).

Anyway, here's an example of an axios request:

```
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Take a look at the docs for more info, different requests, params, and more.
Best of luck!